# How jquery uses the Regular Expression method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just learned jquery and encountered a problem!
I want to use Regular Expression to add the thousandth symbol to the value obtained in the variable, but I have encountered some obstacles~
I found such a syntax on the Internet replace( /\B(?

```js
let num = 123456;

$('.show').text(num.replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="show"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your number to string, because replace funtion works only on strings

```js
let num = 123456;
$('.show').text(String(num).replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="show"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.replace()` works on String, and you are trying to use it with an `int` which gives the error. If you can change the type of num to string, it will work.

like

```
 let num = '123456';
```

you can also typecast the num into a string afterwards with `.toString()` function and use that with `.replace()`

```
num.toString()
```

```js
let num = '123456';

$('.show').text(num.replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="show"></p>
```

Comment: First of all~ Thank you for your prompt reply!

But I found that the description of the problem I asked is a bit wrong, what I want to solve is how to add regular expressions if my program is like this

? Is this possible? Because I tried and failed


$('.show').text(123456.replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));

Comment: You can use .replace() only with string as I said in the answer. replace `123456 `with `'123456'` to make it work

Comment: *the description of the problem I asked is a bit wrong* - please add an amendum to your question.  As you already have answers, please don't rewrite the question, but an "Additional Info:" section may help.  It's still unclear exactly what your problem is if it's *not* because it's a number.

Comment: Thank you ~ I have found the answer, still thank you for your help!